# Replace DNN Login page

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

Recently we have upgrade our DNN from v7.4.2 to v9.3.2.

And for security reason we want to have a unique Login page url to prevent hacker for trying to Login to the Website.

I've create a new Login page lets call it "uniqueLogin", add Login module and then set the default Login page to it.

Test it and its working fine, the issue is when typing [domain]/Login on web browser it still show the default Login page, as we don't want this to happen.

I see on some old forum, to create a page call "Login", and put nothing in it.
The problem is, whenever I try to create "login" page, is not allowed.
Got error message "Login is invalid Title" (Login is reserved keyword).

Is there any way to have a unique login page and disable default login page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a rewrite rule in the web.config that send the /Login url to a different page/url/site. The code must be placed in the `<system.webServer>` node.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="NoLogin" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^login$" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}"/>
    </rule>        
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Guess we need to modify web.config to do permanent redirect. Wonder why DNN 9 no longer have "Request Filter".

Comment: I like this better, because query string ?ctl=login also no longer working.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the ideal solution but sounds like you need a way to redirect the users from [domain]/login to "a far far away galaxy" :).
I can recommend a modules that can assist you with this and not just this :)

DNN Sharp's URL Adapter will allow you to redirect all requests for /login to anything you want to... even 404(not found)

Comment: Yes, this is also our first thought. Either only allow certain IP to login or Redirect login page to another.